# How to upload image links to database only after both images have been saved to the storage

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, google-cloud-storage, multer

I am using MERN stack, multer, mongoose and google cloud storage for this project. For simplicity, I use a simpler code to reflect the problem I face.

In this example, `req.files` is an array of 2 images that is going to be put on the storage.

```js
console.log(req.files)  

//output ->  [

//    { fieldname: 'image1',
//    originalname: 'image1.jpg',
//    encoding: '7bit',
//    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
//    buffer:
//     <Buffer ff d8 ff e2 0b f8 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 0b e8 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 6d 6e 74 72 52 47 42 20 58 59 5a 20 07 d9 00 03 00 1b ... >,
//    size: 96807 },

//    { fieldname: 'image2',
//    originalname: 'image2.jpg',
//    encoding: '7bit',
//    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
//    buffer:
//     <Buffer ff d8 ff e2 0b f8 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 0b e8 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 6d 6e 74 72 52 47 42 20 58 59 5a 20 07 d9 00 03 00 1b ... >,
//    size: 96807 }

 ]
```

```js
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID,
    keyFilename: process.env.GCLOUD_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
});
const bucket = storage.bucket(process.env.GCLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET_URL);


exports.blog_post = async (req, res, next) => {

// I am trying to loop through req.files and save them to the storage
  req.files.map(image => {
    const blob = bucket.file(image.originalname);
    const blobWriter = blob.createWriteStream({
      metadata: {
        contentType: image.mimetype,
      },
    });
    blobWriter.on('error', (err) => next(err));
    blobWriter.on('finish', () => {
      if (file.fieldname === "image1") {
        const link1 = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${bucket.name}/o/${encodeURI(blob.name)}?alt=media`;
      } else {
        const link2 = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${bucket.name}/o/${encodeURI(blob.name)}?alt=media`;
      }
    let gallery = new Gallery({
        image1: link1,
        image2: link2
    })
    blog
    .save()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: `successful`,
        })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    })
  })
    blobWriter.end(image.buffer);
  })
```

The code above produces 2 queries in my Database, which is not what I want. What I want is to wait both images upload complete first, then only put together into the database in 1 query. I need something like `Promise.all()`, but I have no idea what can I do.

Edited ***
I have tried this:

```js
exports.blog_post = (req, res, next) => {
  const image1promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    req.files.map(image => {
      if (image.fieldname === "image1") {        
        const blob = bucket.file(image.originalname);
        const blobWriter = blob.createWriteStream({
          metadata: {
            contentType: image.mimetype,
          },
        });
        blobWriter.on('error', (err) => next(err));
        blobWriter.on('finish', () => {
            const coverImageLink = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${bucket.name}/o/${encodeURI(blob.name)}?alt=media`;
          // if (file.fieldname === "blogImage") {
          //   const image1link = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${bucket.name}/o/${encodeURI(blob.name)}?alt=media`;
          // }
      })
        blobWriter.end(image.buffer);
        resolve(image1link);
      }
    })
  });

  const image2promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    req.files.map(image => {
      if (image.fieldname === "image2") {        
        const blob = bucket.file(image.originalname);
        const blobWriter = blob.createWriteStream({
          metadata: {
            contentType: image.mimetype,
          },
        });
        blobWriter.on('error', (err) => next(err));
        blobWriter.on('finish', () => {
            const image2link = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${bucket.name}/o/${encodeURI(blob.name)}?alt=media`;
          // if (image.fieldname === "blogImage") {
          //   const image2link = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${bucket.name}/o/${encodeURI(blob.name)}?alt=media`;
          // }
      })
        blobWriter.end(image.buffer);
        resolve(blogImageLink);
      }
    })
  });

  Promise.all([image1promise, image2promise])
    .then((image1link, image2link) => {
        let blog = new Blog({
            image1: image1link,
            image2: image2link,
        })
        blog
        .save()
        .then(result => {
          res.status(201).json({
            message: `ok`,
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for the attempt I did above!

Instead of having 2 arguments in `then`, I just make it one because the promise is returning an array of links.

My attempt

```js
Promise.all([image1promise, image2promise])
    .then((image1link, image2link) => {
        let blog = new Blog({
            image1: image1link,
            image2: image2link,
        })
```

Solution

```js
Promise.all([image1promise, image2promise])
    .then((imageLinks) => {
        let blog = new Blog({
            image1: imageLinks[0],
            image2: imageLinks[1],
        })
```

Hope this will help those with similar problem as mine